# Store tabular data in Class

Tags: python, class, constants

Is there any standard and pythonic way to store a small table (consisting of a few rows and a few columns) of constant values as a field in a my class definition?

I'm wondering if it is standard to define such a table of defaults in the class definition, or it is recommended to define it somewhere else.

In fact, depending on some user input, I want to use some row of this table as default value to instantiate my class.

Comment: Have you tried using 2D array?

Comment: @sagarr python has no built-in arrays

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask if it is standard to store such a table in class definition, at all.

Comment: @Mostafa if you think my answer is satisfactory, accept it as best answer

Comment: @yunnic_funk I editted my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many possibilities here, you can use multidimensional `lists` (list in lists) or `numpy arrays` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or `pandas dataframes` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Pandas dataframe come along with a lot functionality for tabular data, so look at the documentation of them and consider if this fits for you.